# html index project crash after opening in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, crash

I'm new to CSS and html and my problem is really odd. I was working on my site project and after a few hours I decided to check if it works on Internet Explorer (I work with Chrome). After I opened my html file in IE, my sticky menu (written in JS) stopped working (I can't scroll my site anymore because it goes back top every time I scroll and menu flickers rapidly). It wasn't working on IE since the beginning but after I closed IE, it also started to act like this in Chrome. I haven't done any changes to my html or CSS code. Any ideas or solutions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var NavY = $('#mainmenu').offset().top;

  var stickyNav = function() {
    var ScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollY > NavY) {
      $('#mainmenu').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('#mainmenu').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  };

  stickyNav();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyNav();
  });
});
```

```css
.sticky {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

#mainmenu {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: url("img/ep_naturalblack.png");
  border-top: 7px solid #9e332f;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #9e332f;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  opacity: 0.99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />


  <meta http-equiv="X-Ua-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="logo">some logo text</h1>

    <nav>
      <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

I use IE 11 and chrome 61.0.3163.100.

Comment: Please add which versions of IE and Chrome you are using and on what OS? Also, please add the relevant HTML so we can attempt to recreate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I think what happened here is that when you started testing between the two browsers, you changed the screen size that you were looking at. With your code as is, changing the `position` to fixed causes the content on the page under that element to shift up. This shift up, depending on the amount of content, and the screen height, can cause there to be not enough content to allow scrolling. When this happens, your code kicks in to remove the `sticky` class from your nav bar which shoves the content back down the page.

I have gotten around this by having two navs. One nav will stay exactly where it is initially placed on the page while the second will scroll with the page. This ensures that when you start scrolling, the content below the nav bar will not shift up the page and should remove this stuttering you are seeing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var NavY = $('#mainmenu').offset().top;

  var stickyNav = function() {
    var ScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (ScrollY > NavY) {
      $('#mainmenuScroll').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('#mainmenuScroll').addClass('hidden');
    }
  };

  stickyNav();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyNav();
  });
});
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

#mainmenu, #mainmenuScroll{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: black;
  border-top: 7px solid #9e332f;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #9e332f;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  opacity: 0.99;
}

.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />


  <meta http-equiv="X-Ua-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

</head>
<header>
  <h1 class="logo">some logo text</h1>

  <nav>
    <div id="mainmenu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <nav>
    <div id="mainmenuScroll" class="sticky">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <h1 class="logo">some logo text</h1>
  <h1 class="logo">some logo text</h1>
  <h1 class="logo">some logo text</h1>
  <h1 class="logo">some logo text</h1>
  <h1 class="logo">some logo text</h1>
  <h1 class="logo">some logo text</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I overcome this simply by using css instead of JS to make my menu sticky. But your explanation is helpful as well. Sorry for bad english.